# How can I stop Gnome Shell's drive pop up notifications?

Tags: gnome, mount, notification, nfs, drive

I have an NFS drive mapped in Ubuntu 11.10 using autofs which automatically mounts a drive on every boot. But if I use the Gnome Shell interface, a pop up notification keeps popping up from the bottom-centre of the screen saying the name of the mapped drive and an Eject option.

It pops up about every 5 minutes even though the NFS drive is already always mounted. Any way to stop this?

Comment: I found something helpful here http://superuser.com/questions/370543/how-do-i-configure-gnome-3-so-that-it-doesnt-pop-up-a-dialog-for-open-with-fil and it worked...

Answer (score 12):

Per this [discussion on the Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1878256), install `dconf-tools` and then run the dconf editor (a launcher installed to "System Tools" on my machine).

Navigate to org > gnome > desktop > media-handling and then check the "autorun-never" box. Then simply close the dconf editor.

Comment: excellent answer! here is a handy one-liner:
`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling autorun-never true`

Comment: @Florian, Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for.